# PDFKit Middleware doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleware, pdfkit

I've read that adding the extension ".pdf" to the URL of my application I can generate a pdf file using the PDFKit Middleware but I can't make it work.

My application.rb:

```
require_relative 'boot'
require 'rails/all'
require 'pdfkit'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Ifo
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :it]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :it
    config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
    config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware 
  end
end
```

as stated in PDFKit's documentation, but this makes rails crash.
(using PDFKit 0.8.2 in Rails 5)

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Thank you. I made the correction that you suggested (see post edit). If I add ".pdf" to the url (http://myapp/charts.pdf) the browser tries to load the page but it doesn't display it and never stops loading.

Comment: I've installe wkhtmltopdf and PDFKit works: I can save pdfs generated by queries to db.

Comment: OK, the browser actually stopped loading, with this error:
    command failed (exitstatus=1): /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --quiet --page-size Letter ..etc..

Comment: Ok, Remember that in develpment you need unicorn becouse puma can't manage it, you need a server than can handle more tham one thread , I'm mot on a computer  now, just a help from holidays , tomorow I will add more settings

Comment: Confirmed, I've added the point nº 3, unicorn's example

Comment: Hello Albert, I'm still using passenger with apache so I guess it's not a multithread issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think can be one of this two:

1) Note than in application.rb, where to put each of your lines

```
require 'pdfkit'

module YouApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ....
    config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware 
end
```

2) Have you installed wkhtmltopdf?

https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/wiki/Installing-WKHTMLTOPDF

3) You need a multithreaded server, like unicorn:

in Gemfile:

```
gem 'unicorn'
```

in config/unicorn.conf:

```
worker_processes 3
```

to run server:

```
unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.conf
```